# Invalid thread-spanning operation while running a function in a new thread

Tags: c#

I've been trying to create a function call in a new Thread because if I use my main thread then my application get's too busy and can't be used anymore while the function is running.

Now I've been trying to create the function call inside a new Thread:

```
private void bunifuFlatButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(worker));
    thread.Start();
}

public void worker()
{
    using (var streamReader = File.OpenText(filePath))
    {
        var lines = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Split(new char[] { '\n' });
        var count = lines.Count();

        bunifuProgressBar1.MaximumValue = count;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            string[] words = lines[i].Split(':');
            string hash = mega.GenerateHash(words[0].ToLowerInvariant(), mega.PrepareKey(words[1].ToBytes()));

            bunifuCustomLabel4.Text = "Working: Total: " + count + ". Currently: " + (i + 1) + ".";
            bunifuCustomLabel4.Update();
            bunifuProgressBar1.Value = i + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

But now I receive the following error (Translated using google):

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: Invalid thread-spanning operation: Access to the bunifuCustomLabel4 control was from a thread other than the thread for which it was created.

How could I fix this error? I've been googling solutions but they didn't work also.

My latest attempt:

```
private void bunifuFlatButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThreadStart asyncCall = delegate
    {
        bunifuCustomLabel4.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(worker));
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(worker));
    thread.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't update the UI from a background thread. You'll have to invoke the update to the UI thread from the background using `Control.Invoke()`

When you need to update the UI, you can do something similar to this:

```
if (myControl.InvokeRequired)
{
    myControl.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {this.Text = "Updated";});
}
```